# Matching the limits of integration with the proper variables in a complicated case when using scipy.integrate.nquad

Tags: python, scipy, integration, numerical-integration

I need to integrate expressions containing powers of the function:

```
Hb = U1.U2*U3.U4 + (permutations of the first term like U1.U3*U2.U4) 
           + Determinant of the matrix [U1,U2,U3,U4].
```

The `U`'s are 4D unit vectors on different sites, so site 1 has

```
U1 = [ Cos(t21), Sin(t21)*Sin(t11)*Cos(p1), 
       Sin(t21)*Sin(t11)Sin(p1), Sin(t21)*Cos(t11) ],
```

where `t21` refers to the angle `theta_2` on site 1. This means that `Hb` has a large number of terms with 12 variables each.

I have to integrate terms like `Hb^5`, attempting to do this using `scipy.integrate.nquad` is the problem. I can't tell which of the integrals is done first, so how do I specify the limits of integration to match the proper variables?

Comment: Please format your answer so it is easier to read

Comment: What is a "site"?

Comment: The order of the limits corresponds to the order of the variables, and that order is defined by you. Integration is left-to-right for inner-to-outer integrals.